# Python3: Weird issue with reading a list of ints from a file

Tags: python

I have come across a strange issue when reading lists of ints from a txt file. I have tried quite a few solutions I have found online, however, I have had no luck.

I am working on a program to convert from ASCII code to plaintext.

Whenever the program reads the text file of ASCII codes and puts it in a list I get the following output.

[Seems like it is coming out as some sort of encoded output as it correlates with the numbers in the list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q98Z4.jpg)

[Here is the list of ASCII codes that I am trying to read. As you can see this correlates with the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36luF.jpg)

Below is the code that is leading to this output.

I'm unsure if this is an issue with the code or potentially an issue with my install of Python?

Thanks in advance all :)

```
##################################################################################################
# ARGPARSE SETUP #

#argparse allows user to input the file path when executing the script
import argparse

#Will show as a comment when the user does -h
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A script for converting ASCII to plain text.")

#adds the -f argument to read in the filename
parser.add_argument("-f", help="Used to input the list of ASCII. Usage: asciiTT -f filename.txt" , default="")

#setting user input as file variable
parsedFile = parser.parse_args()

##################################################################################################
# SANITISING USER INPUT #

#converting to string
fileInitialStr = str(parsedFile)

#slicing off shite from the start
sliceFile = fileInitialStr[13:]
i = 0


#while loop to find the end of the file name
while i < len(sliceFile):
    if sliceFile[i] == "t":

            if sliceFile[i-1] == "x":

                if sliceFile[i-2] == "t":
                    cleanFile = sliceFile[:i+1]
                    i = len(sliceFile)

                else:
                    i+=1

            else:
                i+=1

    else:
        i += 1


##################################################################################################
# LIST FOR ASCII CHARS #

#List of all ASCII characters in order -- missing one of the weird single quotes

ascii = ["NULL" , "START OF HEADING" , "START OF TEXT" , "END OF TEXT" , "END OF TRANSMISSION" , "ENQUIRY" , "ACKNOWLEDGE" , "BELL" , "BACKSPACE" , "HORIZONTAL TAB" , "LINE FEED" , "VERTICAL TAB" , "FORM FEED" , "CARRIAGE RETURN" , "SHIFT OUT" , "SHIFT IN" , "DATA LINK ESCAPE" , "DEVICE CONTROL 1" , "DEVICE CONTROL 2" , "DEVICE CONTROL 3" , "DEVICE CONTROL 4" , "NEGATIVE ACKNOWLEDGE" , "SYNCHRONOUS IDLE" , "END OF TRANS BLOCK" , "CANCEL" , "END OF MEDIUM" , "SUBSTITUTE" , "ESCAPE" , "FILE SEPERATOR" , "GROUP SEPERATOR" , "RECORD SEPERATOR" , "UNIT SEPERATOR" , "SPACE" , "!" , "\"" , "#" , "$" , "%" , "&" , "\'" , "\(" , "\)" , "*" , "+" , "" , "-" , "." , "/" , "0" , "1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , ":" , ";" , "<" , "=" , ">" , "?" , "@" , "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H" , "I" , "J" , "K" , "L" , "M" , "N" , "O" , "P" , "Q" , "R" , "S" , "T" , "U" , "V" , "W" , "X" , "Y" , "Z" , "\[" , "\\" , "\]" , "^" , "_" , "\`" , "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h" , "i", "j" , "k" , "l" , "m" , "n" , "o" , "p" , "q" , "r" , "s" , "t" , "u" , "v" , "w" , "x" , "y" , "z" , "\{" , "|" , "\}" , "~" , "DEL"]


##################################################################################################
# LIST FOR INPUTTED ASCII CHARS

asciiIn = []


##################################################################################################
# OPENING USER FILE #

#opening file with sanatised input
userFile = open(cleanFile , "rt")


for line in userFile:
    asciiIn.append(line)


print(asciiIn)
print("\n\n\nworking on it...\n\n\n")


##################################################################################################
```

Comment: Please include relevant sample data as *text*, not as links to images. Also, please provide a [mre] - most of the code you provided seems irrelevant to your actual problem.

Comment: It seems like you're file is encoded as a UTF-16 text file (i.e. two bytes for each character) with a BOM (the first two bytes you can see in your file - ÿ corresponds to ascii 255 in cp1252/latin-1). Try giving `encoding='utf-16-le' or `encoding='utf-16' to your `open` call.

Comment: @MatsLindh

Thank you so much! I was so sure it had to be something to do with encoding but couldn't find an answer for what the exact issue was anywhere!

Adding `encoding='utf-16'` to the open call fixed it :)

Comment: why are you doing `fileInitialStr = str(parsedFile)`??? `parsedFile` is an ArgumentParser object, no?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga

I did this to convert whatever the user inputs during the command to run the script to a file name that I can call later on.

Basically taking user input from the command line like this:

py asciiTT.py -f test.txt

This will read the file test.txt that is in the same directory as the script.


(Context -- I am not a developer, I write quick scripts for use in CTF's, Bug bounty etc, and just ran into a weird problem and wanted to make sure I can solve it if it ever happens again. Due to this, I know my code is definitely NOT efficient or even best practice.

Comment: all of that parsing code can be removed, the **whole point** of the argparse is to do that for you. You just want something like: `args = parser.parse_args()` then `cleanFile = args.f`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're file is encoded as a UTF-16 text file (i.e. two bytes for each character) with a BOM (the first two bytes you can see in your file - ÿ corresponds to ascii 255 in cp1252/latin-1).

You can tell `open` to open the file with `utf-16` as the encoding by giving it the `encoding` parameter:

```
open(file_name , 'r', encoding='utf-16')
```